# How to specify generic type in this case for GSON

Tags: java, gson

I have following code to illustrate my problem:

First, I define the Box class and Cat class

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T data;

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
public class Cat {
    private String name;
    private Integer age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Then I define the `GsonUtils` (static class) that aims to serialize some json string into an object of `Box<T>`

```
public class GsonUtils {

    public static <T> Box<T> json2BoxObject(String json) {
        Type tpe = new TypeToken<Box<T>>(){}.getType();
        return  new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, tpe);
    }

}
```

1. If I could provide a `Cat` type to `json2BoxObject` method, then I would get a `Box<Cat>`
2. If I could provide a `Dog` Type to `json2BoxObject` method, then I would get a `Box<Dog>`

However, I don't know how to provide a type to `json2BoxObject`,this is the question I am asking

With the above code, give the `json2BoxObject` with json string `{"data":{"name":"Kitty","age":1}}`, I would like to get a `Box<Cat>` object, but I get a Box[Map]

Comment: am not sure if i got what u need, but you may have to pass the type as well to `json2java`, so ur method will look like this `json2Java(String json, Type t)` and use this `type` argument in `.create().fromJson(json, type);` [note: don't use `tpe` anymore]

Comment: want to add, if you are creating an instance of `GsonUtils` to call json2java, then may be if you add type param to the class `GsonUtils <T>` this will fix the issue too, but you are not instantiating it, cuz json2java is static, right?

Comment: @Yazan. Thanks for your comments. for your comment #2, I would like GsonUtil to be static, that is `json2Java` is a static method, so that I don't think `GsonUtils[T]` makes sense. for your comment #1, Yes, I can pass a Type to as the 2nd parameter to json2Java, The Type should be  `Type tpe = new TypeToken<Box<Cat>>() {}.getType(); `but that is what I don't want to define my method..I want to constraint that the json can be deserialized to something of Box, if I pass the type `Cat`, then I would get a Box<Cat>

Comment: i did not understand your **constrain** you will still get Box<T> which means not only Box<Cat> if that what you mean, can u plz explain more ?

Comment: @Yazan. Thanks for your comment, I refine my question, hope this makes what I am saying clear

Answer (score 0):

At some point you need to mention Cat or Dog. I created Type using Box and passed it in a `json2Java` method.

```
String msg ="{\"data\":{\"name\":\"Kitty\",\"age\":1}}";
Type type = new TypeToken<Box<Cat>>(){}.getType();
Box<Cat> obj = GsonUtils.json2Java(msg, type);
System.out.println(obj);
```

And `json2Java` method is :

```
public static <T> Box<T> json2Java(String json, Type type) {
    Box<T> box = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(json, type);
    return box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @prasath for the help. Yes, normally, `json2Java` should be implemented as you posted, the key point is that the user provides the `Type`. I would ask if it is possible to only provide the generic type of Box, like Cat,Dog as my question asks. Looks it is more general question about Java generics

Comment: Without mention Cat or Dog how you are expecting Cat ?

Comment: Thanks @prasath. That's what I am asking, Is it possible somehow providing the `json2Java` method with type information like Cat or Dog...